# Initializing pointer struct - what does it look like in memory?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have this code

```
typedef struct CAR
{
    char name[20];
    int price;
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;         
    CAR *p;
    p = new CAR[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> p[i].price;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout<< p[i].price;
    delete []p;
}
```

Does the pointer point to name location in memory?

My English is so bad I struggle to make my point, please ask me to clarify things before down voting.

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING AT US?

Comment: It looks like nothing. The program doesn't do anything, so everything is optimized away.

Comment: Please check this link out http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: Yes, a pointer to a struct is also a pointer to the first element in the struct.

Comment: The address of an object and the address of its first member variable is always the same per the standard.  Anything else may be different.  In this case though you pointer points to nothing.

Comment: Why don't you just print them? `Clarifying things before down voting`

Comment: @SurajeetBharati I added some lines

Comment: @KenWhite sorry

Comment: alright i will check it out later @I'mhereforWinterHats

Comment: good god , the stackoverflow communtiy is so unforgiving i dont know what to do to please them...... i love this site but this is too much

Comment: well, thanks for fixing it.... @SurajeetBharati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer, named `p`, hasn't been initialized so it doesn't point to anything interesting.

You need to construc an array of objects on the heap with:

```
CAR* p = new CAR[4];
```

`p` now points to an array of 4 instances of the `struct` CAR;

`delete` this with the array `delete` with:

```
delete [] p;
```

Comment: @SurajeetBharati Thanks, didn't see the `C` tag.  Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: It seems like OP is using c++ now.

Comment: i understand them both but for this question i was using a c++ compiler

Comment: @AreyMSalih Glad this helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

The full answer depends on how your compiler is configured. The first 20 bytes of the memory location stored in the pointer will correspond to the `name` field of your structure. Depending on the alignment configuration, there will be 0 or more empty bytes representing padding that will place your second field, `price`, on an alignment boundary.

Single, two, and four-byte alignment will result in no padding, as the 20 byte size of `name` is divisible by those values. Eight-byte alignment will result in 4 bytes of padding between your two fields.

Comment: thank you for taking your time to answer, it helped a lot.